# Shortest word in a dictionary containing all letters

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview.

Given an array of characters, find the shortest word in a dictionary that contains all the characters. Also, propose an implementation for the dictionary that would optimize this function call.

for e.g. char[] chars = { 'R' , 'C' }. The result should be the word "CAR".

I could not come up with anything that would run reasonably quickly. I thought of pre-processing the dictionary by building a hash table to retrieve all words of a particular length. Then I could only think of retrieving all words in the increasing order of length and checking if the required characters were present in any of those ( maybe by using a bitmask . )

Comment: Actually the first result should be Cr, abbreviation for Chromium :D

Answer (score 5):

This is a common software interview question, and its solution is this: sort the dictionary itself by length and sort each value alphabetically. When given the characters, sort them and find the needed letters.

Answer (score 2):

First sort the dictionary in ascending order of length.

For each letter, construct a bit map of the locations in the dictionary of the words containing that letter. Each bit map will be long, but there will not be many.

For each search, take the intersection of the bitmaps for the letters in the array. The first one bit in the result will be at the index corresponding to the location in the dictionary of the shortest word containing all the letters.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are better, but I realized this is entirely precomputable.

- For each word

  - sort the letters and remove duplicates
  - The sequence of letters can be viewed as a bitmask, A=0bit, B=1bit...Z=26bit.  Set the bits of a mask A according to the letters in this word.
  - For each combination of set bits in the mask A, make a subset mask B

    - If there is already a word associated with this mask B

      - and this word is shorter, replace the associated word with this one
      - otherwise try next B
    - If there is no  word associated with mask B

      - Associate this word with mask B.

This would take a huge amount of setup time, and the subsequent association storage would be in the vicinity of 1.7GB, but you'd be able to find the shortest word containing a superset of the letters in O(1) time guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious preprocessing is to sort all words in the dictionary by their length and alphabetical re-ordering: "word" under "dorw", for example. Then you can use general search algorithms (e.g., regex) to search for the letters you need. An efficient (DFA) search requires only one pass over the dictionary in the worst case, and much less if the first match is short.

Answer (score 0):

### Pre processing

a. Sort words into alphabetic char arrays. Retain mapping from sorted to original word

b. Split dictionary by word length as you suggest

c. Sort entries in each word length set alphabetically

### On function call

1. Sort char array alphabetically
2. Start with group of same length as array
3. Loop through entries testing for characters until first letter of entry lexicographically greater than first in your char array then break. If match then return original word (see a above for mapping)
4. Back to 2 for next longest word group

Interesting extensions. Multiple words might map to same entry in a. Which one (s) should you return...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class ShortestWordFinder
{
    public ShortestWordFinder(IEnumerable<string> dictionary)
    {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public string ShortestWordContaining(IEnumerable<char> chars)
    {
        var wordsContaining = dictionary.Where(s =>
        {
            foreach (var c in chars)
            {
                if (!s.Contains(c))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf(c), 1);
            }

            return true;
        }).ToList();

        if (!wordsContaining.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }

        var minLength = wordsContaining.Min(word => word.Length);
        return wordsContaining.First(word => word.Length == minLength);
    }

    private readonly IEnumerable<string> dictionary;
}
```

Simple test:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xunit;

public class ShortestWordFinderTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Works()
    {
        var words = new[] { "dog", "moose", "gargoyle" };
        var finder = new ShortestWordFinder(words);
        Trace.WriteLine(finder.ShortestWordContaining("o"));
        Trace.WriteLine(finder.ShortestWordContaining("oo"));
        Trace.WriteLine(finder.ShortestWordContaining("oy"));
        Trace.WriteLine(finder.ShortestWordContaining("eyg"));
        Trace.WriteLine(finder.ShortestWordContaining("go"));
        Assert.Null(finder.ShortestWordContaining("ooo"));
    }
}
```